# Why role also deleted while i remove permissoin from it?

Tags: laravel

I am using Spatie roles and permission package.
I have assigned permission to roles.
It stores in role_permission table
now i want to delete permission from role
i have tried

```
$role = Role::find($id);
$role->revokePermissionTo($request->permission_id);
```

but roles also get deleted from roles table

Comment: Did you try to remove the role from permissions, instead of revoking permission from a role?
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/master/docs/basic-usage/basic-usage.md

A permission can be removed from a role using 1 of these methods:

```
$role->revokePermissionTo($permission);
$permission->removeRole($role);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$role->revokePermissionTo()` accepts `Permission` object or array and `Permission` name string or name string array. But you are passing the `permission_id`. That could be the issue.
You can try fetching the `Permission` object by `permission_id` first and pass it to the `revokePermissionTo()`.

See the function signature here: 
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/be87e2918a9fad30e5257bc336c89225c3e6eb5a/src/Traits/HasPermissions.php#L384